# Excel Vba to open a file using .range as the directory

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that needs to open files but the problem is everyday it is in a new folder labeled according to the day. Example today would be C:\WORK\122315\fileexample.xlsx

How I usually open files with dates is by entering the date in cell A1 as a TEXT "122315" then use Date1 = Range("A1").Value in vba. My question is what do I do if the date is not in the file, but in the subfolder?

```
    Date1 = Range("A1").Value

    ChDir "C:\WORK\Date1"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\WORK\Date1\fileexample.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\WORK\" & Range("A1").Value & "\fileexample.xlsx"
```

FYI you don't need to use `ChDir` if you're passing the full file path to `Open`